# building a reminder in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, reminders

I am a student and working on `winform c#`. I have a small app and I want to add a new feature of memo reminder. For example, when I type something in a text box, the app saves it and set a timer of 8 hours. If the app is running, then a message should popup with the message I have saved.

It's not clear to me if I should use a database for reminding the entries or something else provided by c#. As far as I know all thing are automated. Is there anything which will help me to build this functionality, like a timer??

Comment: How are you storing your reminders - in a database table?

Comment: Have you tried looking for `timer` on MSDN?

Comment: You could start a background thread and tell it to run that thread for a provided time and int the `runworkercompleated` you could show a message box.  Kinda brute force but it might work.

Comment: What happens if you close the app now, and open it again. Shall it honor previous reminder?

Comment: Seeing as you are just learning, you need to consider which data source you find easier to use. XML? SQL?

Comment: @LukeHennerley i know sql server and i am going to use that. can you help me?

Comment: @Yahya i when restart the app it just gives the expiration message that the notification is expired if the time is gone and if the time is remaining then it will be same as the previous reminders

Comment: @aquibRocks I have posted a simple flow, if that helps. See the answers below.

Comment: Database vs Local File Pro/Con: Database gives you strongly-typed data (pro) and memos can follow around the user, not the machine (pro), but to use the app requires a network connection (possible con) and increases complexity of the solution (i.e., maintaining a DB; con). Local file is a standalone, no network, solution (possible pro), but requires parsing the data yourself (con, but can be made easier by many pre-existing parsers, like for XML).

Answer (score 4):

Store somewhere in the txt file if using database is not possible. 
Like this:

> 3.20.2013 11:20:00 | Remind me something.

Then your timer checks every minute or so.

UPDATE:

Example:

```
DateTime savedTime = Convert.ToDateTime("date from the text file");
if(DateTime.Now >= savedTime)
{
     MessageBox.Show("reminder from the text file");
}
```

UPDATE2:

```
string pathToStoreTXT = Application.UserAppDataPath;
```

`pathToStoreTXT` has the path something like: "C:\Users\UserName\AppData". Your timer need's to check for that folder all the time. Name your txt file like "MyReminders.txt".

Comment: +1 low tech solution.

Comment: sir but how that can be possible that timer will check only the date and time part????

Comment: @aquibRocks `DateTime.Parse(string.Split('|')[0])`. Obviously there's more to it than that, but if you are not yet skilled at file parsing, then do a web search first, then ask any specifics you don't understand.

Comment: sir sir. one more question. i have to save the text file in the hard drive? the how can i locate the location in the timer to find the file in that specific folder?

Comment: @aquibRocks If you want to go with local file, I'd recommend either `Application.ExecutablePath` or `Application.UserAppDataPath` then just append your static filename, like `Application.UserAppDataPath + "\\WhateverNameIGiveMyFile.txt"`

Comment: sir what is this?? what is this known as? first can you tell me i am not a prefessional programmer which knows every thing. i have just started c#
sorry but i cant understand what you are telling can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Simple flow would be:

1. When app is run, check if file is created or not. This file will store your data!
2. Check if there is any record in the file or not. 
   2a. Show expired messages and clear them too.
3. Add timer like Dilshod has suggested. 
   3a. Convert reminder datetime as timestamp and concatenate it with message to store in text file
4. Create at a timer object with tick event every 1 minute, something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). (Obviously you will need to set frequency which is passed as parameter)

Comment: sir this is the suggestion that, the fucntion should be like this or like that. but how can i achive this?? how can i check that file?? you are telling to create a text file for all the reminders and updating the text file??? means that no one textfile or each reminder??

Comment: One text file to store all reminders. Simple thing is to breakdown your problem first. Try learning how timer works in C# first. And then take it to next step.

Comment: Stackoverflow is to solve your problems, not to teach you coding unfortunately!

Comment: sir i know how timer works. it have a tick event but how can i save the file?? and update the file if the file is created?? can you help me in that?

Comment: @aquibRocks http://www.csharp-station.com/howto/readwritetextfile.aspx